# Magento Invoice Change From Tax to VAT

Tags: magento

I am trying to change the defualt wording in Magento Invoice templates. I have changed the Tax to VAT in the `app/local/en_US` folder which has updated it in the backend of the website so it now all says VAT instead of Tax.

The problem is that this dosen't seem to update my invoice's.

I need where it says Tax to say VAT.

This is what is coming through at the moment:

```
Subtotal  £100.97  
Shipping & Handling  £8.00  
Internal Credit  £0.00  
Grand Total (Excl.Tax)  £108.97  
Tax  £20.19 
Grand Total (Incl.Tax)  £129.16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the right rows in locale files to change that. Here's a quick grep to reveal where term TAX is used:

```
grep 'Tax' app/locale/ -rsn


app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:250:"Customer Tax Classes","Customer Tax Classes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:332:"Excl. Tax","Excl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:406:"Import and Export Tax Rates","Import and Export Tax Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:416:"Incl. Tax","Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:506:"Manage Tax Rules","Manage Tax Rules"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:507:"Manage Tax Zones and Rates","Manage Tax Zones and Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:702:"Product Tax Classes","Product Tax Classes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:881:"Tax","Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Bundle.csv:19:"Excl. Tax","Excl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Bundle.csv:24:"Incl. Tax","Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:36:"Add Tax","Add Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:322:"Incl. Tax","Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:642:"Tax","Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:699:"Total incl. Tax: %1$s","Total incl. Tax: %1$s"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv:116:"Estimate Shipping and Tax","Estimate Shipping and Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv:117:"Excl. Tax","Excl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv:133:"Incl. Tax","Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Cms.csv:45:"Customer Tax Class Information","Customer Tax Class Information"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Cms.csv:93:"Product Tax Class Information","Product Tax Class Information"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv:320:"Show Tax/VAT Number","Show Tax/VAT Number"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv:337:"Tax Class","Tax Class"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv:338:"Tax/VAT number","Tax/VAT number"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Downloadable.csv:28:"Excl. Tax","Excl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Downloadable.csv:35:"Incl. Tax","Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_GoogleCheckout.csv:28:"Disable Default Tax Tables","Disable Default Tax Tables"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_GoogleCheckout.csv:29:"Discount Tax","Discount Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Payment.csv:100:"Tax Amount","Tax Amount"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Paypal.csv:56:"Buyer\'s Tax ID","Buyer\'s Tax ID"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Paypal.csv:57:"Buyer\'s Tax ID Type","Buyer\'s Tax ID Type"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Reports.csv:91:"Order Taxes Report Grouped by Tax Rate","Order Taxes Report Grouped by Tax Rate"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Reports.csv:151:"Tax","Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Rss.csv:48:"Tax","Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:229:"Excl. Tax","Excl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:272:"Incl. Tax","Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:438:"Order Taxes Report Grouped by Tax Rates","Order Taxes Report Grouped by Tax Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:563:"Refund Shipping (Excl. Tax)","Refund Shipping (Excl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:564:"Refund Shipping (Incl. Tax)","Refund Shipping (Incl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:615:"Sales Tax","Sales Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:710:"Tax","Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:711:"Tax Amount","Tax Amount"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:712:"Tax Percent","Tax Percent"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv:784:"Total Tax","Total Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:4:"Add New Tax Rate","Add New Tax Rate"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:5:"Add New Tax Rule","Add New Tax Rule"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:15:"Apply Customer Tax","Apply Customer Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:17:"Apply Tax On","Apply Tax On"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:18:"Apply discount on price including tax is calculated based on store tax, if ""Apply Tax after Discount"" is selected.","Apply discount on price including tax is calculated based on store tax, if ""Apply Tax after Discount"" is selected."
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:30:"Customer Tax Class","Customer Tax Class"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:31:"Customer Tax Class Information","Customer Tax Class Information"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:32:"Customer Tax Classes","Customer Tax Classes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:36:"Default Tax Destination Calculation","Default Tax Destination Calculation"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:40:"Display Full Tax Summary","Display Full Tax Summary"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:46:"Display Zero Tax Subtotal","Display Zero Tax Subtotal"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:50:"Edit Tax Rate","Edit Tax Rate"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:52:"Excl. Tax","Excl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:53:"Excl. Tax:","Excl. Tax:"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:54:"Excluding Tax","Excluding Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:55:"Export Tax Rates","Export Tax Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:56:"Grand Total (Excl. Tax)","Grand Total (Excl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:57:"Grand Total (Excl.Tax)","Grand Total (Excl.Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:58:"Grand Total (Incl. Tax)","Grand Total (Incl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:59:"Grand Total (Incl.Tax)","Grand Total (Incl.Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:60:"Grand Total Excl. Tax","Grand Total Excl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:61:"Grand Total Incl. Tax","Grand Total Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:62:"Import / Export Tax Rates","Import / Export Tax Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:63:"Import Tax Rates","Import Tax Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:64:"Inc. Tax","Inc. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:65:"Incl. Tax","Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:66:"Incl. Tax:","Incl. Tax:"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:67:"Include Tax In Grand Total","Include Tax In Grand Total"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:68:"Including Tax","Including Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:69:"Including and Excluding Tax","Including and Excluding Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:72:"Manage Customer Tax Classes","Manage Customer Tax Classes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:73:"Manage Product Tax Classes","Manage Product Tax Classes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:74:"Manage Tax Rates","Manage Tax Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:75:"Manage Tax Rules","Manage Tax Rules"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:76:"Manage Tax Zones & Rates","Manage Tax Zones & Rates"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:80:"New Tax Rate","New Tax Rate"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:88:"Product Tax Class","Product Tax Class"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:89:"Product Tax Class Information","Product Tax Class Information"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:90:"Product Tax Classes","Product Tax Classes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:102:"Shipping & Handling (Excl.Tax)","Shipping & Handling (Excl.Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:103:"Shipping & Handling (Incl.Tax)","Shipping & Handling (Incl.Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:104:"Shipping & Handling Tax","Shipping & Handling Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:105:"Shipping (Excl. Tax)","Shipping (Excl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:106:"Shipping (Incl. Tax)","Shipping (Incl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:107:"Shipping Excl. Tax (%s)","Shipping Excl. Tax (%s)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:108:"Shipping Incl. Tax (%s)","Shipping Incl. Tax (%s)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:114:"Subtotal (Excl. Tax)","Subtotal (Excl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:115:"Subtotal (Excl.Tax)","Subtotal (Excl.Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:116:"Subtotal (Incl. Tax)","Subtotal (Incl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:117:"Subtotal (Incl.Tax)","Subtotal (Incl.Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:118:"Tax","Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:119:"Tax Calculation Based On","Tax Calculation Based On"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:120:"Tax Calculation Method Based On","Tax Calculation Method Based On"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:121:"Tax Class for Shipping","Tax Class for Shipping"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:122:"Tax Classes","Tax Classes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:123:"Tax Identifier","Tax Identifier"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:124:"Tax Rate","Tax Rate"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:125:"Tax Rate Information","Tax Rate Information"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:126:"Tax Rule Information","Tax Rule Information"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:127:"Tax Rules","Tax Rules"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:128:"Tax Section","Tax Section"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:129:"Tax Titles","Tax Titles"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:130:"Tax rate cannot be removed. It exists in tax rule","Tax rate cannot be removed. It exists in tax rule"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:131:"Tax rates at the same priority are added, others are compounded.","Tax rates at the same priority are added, others are compounded."
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv:149:"You cannot delete this tax class as it is used in Tax Rules. You have to delete the rules it is used in first.","You cannot delete this tax class as it is used in Tax Rules. You have to delete the rules it is used in first."
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Weee.csv:3:"Apply Tax To FPT","Apply Tax To FPT"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Weee.csv:11:"Fixed Product Tax","Fixed Product Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Weee.csv:12:"Fixed Product Taxes","Fixed Product Taxes"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Weee.csv:18:"Total Incl. Tax","Total Incl. Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv:275:"Grand Total (Excl. Tax)","Grand Total (Excl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv:276:"Grand Total (Incl. Tax)","Grand Total (Incl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv:531:"Subtotal (Excl. Tax)","Subtotal (Excl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv:532:"Subtotal (Incl. Tax)","Subtotal (Incl. Tax)"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv:536:"Tax","Tax"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv:564:"Total incl. Tax: %1$s","Total incl. Tax: %1$s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your text to one of these CSV's to "translate" it to another string, like `"Grand Total (Excl.Tax)";"Grand Total (Excl.VAT)"`

Another way is to change directly into `tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml` file

Comment: I have done both of these but it doesn't seem to be updating the invoice email. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It can be store on database. Look for Transactional E-mail on Administration.

Comment: not sure what you mean I have set up Transactional Emails but it use's a block for the Grand Totals I think.